# How do I send my SIGINT to the foreground job (writing own shell)?

Tags: c, shell, signals

I know I have to use the kill(pid, signal) function. The problem is, that I don't know how to get the current foreground job. I tried tcgetpgrp but this logged me out of the PC (makes sense).
What I'm asking for is if anyone knows a method for doing this.

Comment: The shell decides which job is foreground or background, it should put the process group ID in a variable and use that.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? If you are trying to implement Ctrl+C, that's not the way to go. SIGINT is sent to the foreground process group by the terminal driver, not by the shell.

Comment: `tcsetpgrp` is the way you tell the terminal driver which process group contains the foreground job. You also need to use `setpgid()` to make a child process a process group leader, so that it will be in a separate process group from the shell.